# SSH into iPhone without "OpenSSH"-like IPA?

Tags: iphone, backup, jailbreak, ssh, remote-control

My iPhone‘s screen is broken and touch doesn’t respond. I would like to do a backup. The problem is iTunes requires a confirmation from the iPhone to do the backup.

My idea is to jailbreak the device and establish a SSH-tunnel. After that I would like to install an IPA to remotely click the trust button from my computer.

But now it seems to me that there is a requirement of something like OpenSSH to be installed to do that.

Does anyone know if my idea could work anyway ?

If someone has a better idea for backing up feel free to tell me :D

Answer (score 1):

Does any part of the touch screen respond (doesn't matter where)? If so, you could have VoiceOver help you enter the passcode, as described in this blog post I wrote: https://deciphertools.com/blog/iphone-passcode-broken-screen/

If not, there's a comment on there about using a USB keyboard via a USB lightning connector. I haven't vetted this idea myself yet, but maybe could help?

Comment: The whole screen doesn’t work. But a usb keyboard seems to be worth a try. Thank u!